# Reset Homebrew Formula

Tags: macos, homebrew

While trying to install FreeTDS via Homebrew, I ran `brew edit freetds`.  I edited the file.  I'd like to restore the Recipe file (freetds.rb) to it's orinal state in case I introduced a typo into it.

Is there a way to reset a brew formula file?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Homebrew recipes are managed via Git, so you can just `git checkout freetds.rb` to wipe out your local changes.

Comment: Where is the .git repo (so I can cd to that directory and run the command)?

Comment: The repository covers everything in `/usr/local`. (There are some pretty big, broad exclusions defined in `.gitignore`, of course.)

Answer (score 39):

You need to reset your Cellar git repo.

```
cd `brew --cellar`
git reset --hard HEAD
brew upgrade <formula>
```

That should do it!

Comment: Alternately, if it's not the main brew but a tap, it'll be in `/usr/local/Library/Taps/*`

Comment: In Homebrew 1.0.4 on macOS Sierra the first instruction is `cd "$(brew --repo)"` whereas the last instruction might not work for some formulas (e.g. `aircrack-ng`) but a very simple `brew uninstall <formula> && brew install <formula>` works like a charm.

Comment: In my case: cd $(brew --repo)/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/

Answer (score 20):

You can reset all formulas with:
`brew update-reset`

> The update-reset version of this command resets all formulae to be identical to the contents of their remote repositories, deleting any local changes. It is only used as a last-resort effort to fix a problem (it’s like unplugging Homebrew and plugging it back in).

Answer (score 3):

For Homebrew version 2.1.4 on macOS Mojave the following command will work from anywhere for `homebrew-core` formulas:

```
git -C $(brew --repo)/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core checkout Formula/$FORMULA_NAME.rb
```

Where `$FORMULA_NAME` is the name of the formula you have edited.